# In Flutter, how do I pass a void function as an argument, from a stateful widget to a child stateless widget?

Tags: flutter

Building a simple to-do app. The problem resides in two widgets: TaskTile and TaskCheckbox. The TaskTile should pass down a Boolean and a Function to change this Boolean to its child TaskCheckbox, which in turn, triggers the void function and actually change it's value.

**TaskTile:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'task_checkbox.dart';

class TaskTile extends StatefulWidget {
  const TaskTile({
    super.key,
    required this.taskName,
  });

  final String taskName;

  @override
  State<TaskTile> createState() => _TaskTileState();
}

class _TaskTileState extends State<TaskTile> {
  bool isChecked = false;

  void checkboxCallback({required bool checkboxState}) {
    setState(() {
      isChecked = !checkboxState;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        Text(
          widget.taskName,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            decoration: isChecked ? TextDecoration.lineThrough : null,
          ),
        ),
        TaskCheckbox(
          checkboxState: isChecked,
          toggleCheckboxState: checkboxCallback(checkboxState: isChecked),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**TaskCheckbox:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TaskCheckbox extends StatelessWidget {
  const TaskCheckbox({
    super.key,
    required this.checkboxState,
    required this.toggleCheckboxState,
  });

  final bool checkboxState;
  final void toggleCheckboxState;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Checkbox(
      value: checkboxState,
      onChanged: (value) {
        toggleCheckboxState;
      },
      checkColor: Colors.black,
      activeColor: const Color(0xff7df9ff),
      side: const BorderSide(
        color: Colors.white70,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

With the code above, I keep getting this error:

```
lib/widgets/task_tile.dart:39:32: Error: This expression has type 'void' and can't be used.
          toggleCheckboxState: checkboxCallback(checkboxState: isChecked),
```

Comment: Change final void toggleCheckboxState; to final Function(bool) toggleCheckboxState; in your TaskCheckbox

Answer (score 0):

first, in the `TaskCheckbox`, change the declaration of the `toggleCheckboxState` to this:

```
final void Function(bool) toggleCheckboxState;
```

then in its `build()` widget, set onChanged like this:

```
// ...
onChanged: toggleCheckboxState,
```

then when you're tying to call it from the `TaskTile` widget, call it like this:

```
  // ...
  toggleCheckboxState: (value) {
    checkboxCallback(checkboxState: value);
  },
```